# Preventing str_replace from commenting the php code that comes in the string

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to make a website, and I'm using a php file as the index (index.php) and pretty much as the page that controls the whole website.

Since it recieves all the requests and returns the pages using `str_replace`, it's all working as it should (as in, it's making the web template work as it should) but the problem is I can't have php code inside the files that are part of the template, only in index.php.

So my question is, is there any way to prevent `str_replace` from turning the php code into comments?

Index.php:

```
<?php

//dirs
$pagesDir = "pages/";
$templatesDir = "templates/";
$errorsDir = "errors/";

if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['page'] != "")
        if (file_exists($pagesDir . $_REQUEST['page'] . ".html"))
            $page_content = file_get_contents($pagesDir . $_REQUEST['page'] . ".html");
    else
        if (file_exists($_REQUEST['page'] . ".html"))
            $page_content = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['pages'] . ".html");
            else
                echo "<h1>Page:" . $_REQUEST['page'] . " does not exist!       Please check the url and try again!</h1>";
} else {
    $page_content = file_get_contents($pagesDir . "home.html");
}

//PLACEHOLDER REPLACEMENT
$page_content = str_replace("!!HEAD!!", file_get_contents($templatesDir .    "head.html"), $page_content);
$page_content = str_replace("!!BODY!!", file_get_contents($templatesDir . "body.html"), $page_content);
$page_content = str_replace("!!FOOT!!", file_get_contents($templatesDir . "eofScripts.html"), $page_content);

//RETURN THE CONTENT OF THE PAGE
echo $page_content;
```

New dispatcher after changes(this one works):

```
<?php
$templatesDir = "templates/";
$pagesDir = "pages/";
$loggedPagesDir = "templates/logged";
$pageExists = false;
$pageContent = null;
require_once('scripts/php/db_conn.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'] . ".php";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['redirect_reason'])) {
    $dialogs->alertDialog("warningDialog", $_SESSION['redirect_reason']);
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_reason']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['user_action'])) {
    $dialogs->alertDialog("infoDialog", $_SESSION['user_action']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_action']);
}

if ($user->is_logged()) { //Only runs beyond this point if user is logged, if not, it will run the other one.
    if (isset($_POST['logout_btn'])) {
        $user->logout();
        $user->redirect("pageDispatcher.php");
    }

    if (isset($page)) {
        if ($page != "") {
            if (file_exists($pagesDir . $page)) {
                $pageExists = true;
                $pageContent = ($pagesDir . $page);
            } else {
                echo "<h1>Page: " . $page . "does not exist! Please check the url and try again</h1>";
            }
        } else {
            $pageExists = true;
            $pageContent = ($pagesDir . "loggedhome.php");
        }
    } else {
        $pageExists = true;
        $pageContent = ($pagesDir . "loggedhome.php");
    }
} else { //Only runs beyond this point if user isn't logged.

    if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
        if ($user->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) == false) {
            $dialogs->loginFailed();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_action'] = "Welcome back " . $_SESSION['user_name'];
            $user->redirect("pageDispatcher.php");
        }
    }

    if (isset($page)) {
        if ($page != "") {
            if (file_exists($pagesDir . $page)) {
                $pageExists = true;
                $pageContent = ($pagesDir . $page);
            } else {
                echo "<h1>Page: " . $page . " does not exist! Please check the url and try again!</h1>";
            }
        } else {
            $pageExists = true;
            $pageContent = ($pagesDir . "home.php");
        }
    } else {
        $pageExists = true;
        $pageContent = ($pagesDir . "home.php");
    }
}
?>

<html>

<?php include($templatesDir . "head.html"); ?>


<body>
<?php
if ($user->is_logged()) {
    include($templatesDir . "loggedBody.html");
} else {
    include($templatesDir . "body.html");
}
include($pageContent);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: Do not use this method unless it's for learning purposes, its bad, can turn out to be quite hard to maintain, and probably will end up being slow since I have so many server side methods of things that I can do client side.**

Comment: ??? post some code or something doesn't make sense what you are asking

Comment: My code probably doesn't make alot of sence, but there ya have it.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to echo his templates as strings, and he sees php tags (and instructions, I guess) in the resulting page.

Comment: nothing obvious there that is making your replacements comments. the problem must be in the markup you did in those files. as a side note, check out twig instead for doing templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the content of page and echo it! Don't do that. Use include('file.html') instead. Just for sake of explanation, (if you have to) do sth like this:

```
$pages=['head.html','body.html','eofScripts.html'];
$page=$_REQUEST['page'];
if(in_array($page,$pages)) include($page);
else echo "<h1>Page: $page does not exist!</h1>";
```

But generally this is bad programming practice. As suggested in comments before do use a template engine.

Comment: It worked, but I had to restructure the way I dispatched the pages, besides I'm doing this without a templating engine because I'm not gonna use a templating engine until I fully understand how to work with php, this project is gonna end up being released but I'm doing it this way for learning purposes, in the release version I will be using Laravel, thanks for the help, I will update my question to include my new dispatcher, and it still uses alot of bad programming practices, I am aware of it, but again, its for learning purposes.